# How to assign values from storage to a variable in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I tried few methods to assign values to variable but could succeed please help.

**Method 1:-**

```
getData() {
        return this.storage.get('products')
          .then(res => {
            return this.cart = res;
          });;
      }
```

Console.log shows undefined

**Method 2:-**

```
cart = [];

getData() {
    return this.storage.get('products')
      .then(res => {
        return this.cart.push(res);
      });;
  }
```

Output : [image: Click Here]

How can i achieve

Cart variable as directly the array list from 0, 1,? [as shown in picture]

Comment: Please `console.log` the res, then we will be able to tell you clearly

Answer (score 2):

Found the Solution

```
//set Cart Storage 
    this.storage.get('products').then((data) => {
      if (data == null) {
        data = [];
      }
      this.cart = data;//re-initialize the items array equal to storage value
      this.cart.push(this.cartItem());
      this.storage.set('products', this.cart);
      console.log("Cart" + this.cart);
    });
```

On Another Page

```
// Retrieving data     
public getData() {
        return this.storage.get('products')
          .then(res => {
            this.cart = [];
            this.cart = res;
            console.log(this.cart);

          });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try logging the value of the res parameter in the console. From there, you can assign the value of *cart* to the correct property in the *res* object.

Comment: In the above question's image which shows the value of Array of 0 which is 0: {} & 1:{} is the res 'm getting in console. how can I assign?

Comment: is that the value of *res* itself? Console.log the res just before the line where you assign the variable and send a screenshot of what you get.

   console.log('res is:', res);

Comment: this is wierd...okay, try this
`getData() {`
    `return this.storage.get('products')`
      `.then(res => {`
        `this.cart = res;`
        `// check value of cart after reassigning it's values`
        `console.log('the cart is:',  this.cart)`
     ` });;`
 ` }`

Comment: great, just what I expected;
remove the variable assignment and everything in the **.then** callback and then run;
   `console.log('res', res, typeof res);`
// Let's see what type of variable res is.

Comment: Lol, I'm not even sure what to ask of you anymore. Try this...
`this.cart = [...res]`;

try this and let me know what cart is afterwards

Comment: Cart: undefined  No success :(